# Javascript string concatenation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a problem with string concatenation. I am making a series of ajax calls and from the results I am building a table, where each element has a bootstrap popover field. In this field I would like to show additional details. Here is the code:

```
...initiate ajax post ...
... other parameters...
function(data){//function called on success
        var popoverContent = 'Sent: ';
        popoverContent = popoverContent.concat(JSON.stringify(obj.value));
        popoverContent = popoverContent.concat('\nReceived: ');
        popoverContent = popoverContent.concat(JSON.stringify(data.error));
        console.log(popoverContent);

... other processing ...
...building table...

'<td> <a class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content='+popoverContent+' data-original-title="Detailed description">'+outcome+'</a></td>'+ ...

...rest of the code ...
```

Now my problem is that while in the console the popoverContent has all the data what I want to display in form of string, in the popover only Sent: gets displayed. If I make popoverContent equal to any other concatenated part it displays that part, but the whole thing it does not.
What am I missing here?

Comment: .concat() is a function for concatenating two Arrays not strings.

Comment: @DeckerWBrower - not true, there is also a [String concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) method

Comment: @MichaelGeary - oh sorry my bad. i've just never seen anyone use it before for obvious reasons. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: No worries, it actually caught me by surprise too! MDN definitely doesn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you have before the `console.log` call, you can use the += operator which is generally easier to read (though not a requirement), like this:

```
var popoverContent = 'Sent: ';
popoverContent += JSON.stringify(obj.value);
popoverContent += '\nReceived: ';
popoverContent += JSON.stringify(data.error);
```

The real problem, however, is in your actual HTML output. You're not surrounding the results with "s. In fact, it will need to be escaped as well. Something like:

```
... '<td>' +
  '<a class="btn large primary" rel="popover" data-content="' +
      popoverContent.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
     .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') +
    '" data-original-title="Detailed description">' +
    outcome +
  '</a>' +
'</td> + ...
```

Comment: Did you try updating the content per my suggestion? Without the "s around your popovercontent, only the first word will show up (which is "Sent:" in this case)

Comment: Your update does the trick :D. Also how do I insert a new line?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I know JS and HTML well, not Twitter-Bootstrap... they probably have their own syntax for it. I'd try \r\n, \n or <br /> if they don't have any readily available documentation.

Comment: The first part of your answer is in error. The `.concat` calls work just as well as `+=`. Consider this code: `var s = 'a'; s = s.concat('b'); console.log(s);` which prints `'ab'`. Perhaps the quoting problem you mentioned is the actual problem?

Comment: I didn't say `.concat` didn't work, I was more saying a different way to format it. I'll add a note that it is a recommendation instead of a requirement.

Comment: Cool, just saw your update. In fact, MDN mentions that `+=` may be faster than `.concat()`, so another good reason to use it. Just helping clarify recommendations vs. bug fixes. :-)

Comment: The solution for the new line is the following: I need to add another replace: `.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')` and when I call the popover, I need to enable html like this: `$('[rel="popover"]').popover({html:true});`